# Python shutil file move in os walk for loop

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, shutil

The code below searches within a directory for any PDFs and for each one it finds it moves into the corresponding folder which has '_folder' appended.
Could it be expressed in simpler terms? It's practically unreadable. Also if it can't find the folder, it destroys the PDF!

```
import os
import shutil

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path_variable):
        for file1 in files:
            if file1.endswith('.pdf') and not file1.startswith('.'):
                filenamepath = os.path.join(root, file1)
                name_of_file = file1.split('-')[0]
                folderDest = filenamepath.split('/')[:9]
                folderDest = '/'.join(folderDest)
                folderDest = folderDest + '/' + name_of_file + '_folder'
                shutil.move(filenamepath2, folderDest)
```

Really I want to traverse the same directory after constructing the variable name_of_file and if that variable is in a folder name, it performs the move. However I came across issues trying to nest another for loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by John Zwinck is correct, except it contains a bug where if the destination folder already exists, a folder within that folder is created and the pdf is moved to that location. I have fixed this by adding a 'break' statement within the inner for loop (for filename in files).

The code below now executes correctly. Looks for folder named as the pdf's first few characters (taking the prefix split at '-') with '_folder' at the tail, if it exists the pdf is moved into it. If it doesn't, one is created with the prefix name and '_folder' and pdf is moved into it.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path_variable):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf') and not filename.startswith('.'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filename_prefix = filename.split('-')[0]
            dest_dir = os.path.join(root, filename_prefix + '_folder')
            if not os.path.isdir(dest_dir):
                os.mkdir(dest_dir)
            os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path_variable):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf') and not filename.startswith('.'):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            filename_prefix = filename.split('-')[0]
            dest_dir = os.path.join(root, filename_prefix + '_folder')
            if not os.path.isdir(dest_dir):
                os.mkdir(dest_dir)
            os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(dest_dir, filename))
```

Comment: If the folder already exists, this actually creates a folder within that folder using the same name and moves the PDF into it, not sure where it is going wrong but that's the result I'm getting

Comment: OK well I'm sure you're willing and able to troubleshoot it from here.  Just step through it with `pdb` or add a bunch of `print` statements and debug it.

Comment: Added break to the 'for filename' loop and this fixed the bug. The loop runs once per PDF and if the folder doesn't exist it correctly creates it and moves each PDF.